# Jetpack Compose:Testing canvas drawings

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, canvas, android-jetpack-compose

I have this Hangman app built using `Jetpack Compose`, which draws Hangman body parts based on wrong guesses.
How do we find these shapes as individual elements(nodes) as all I could find was Canvas having semantic matcher (`Modifier.semantics {contentDescription = "Hangman"}`). But what about drawings in `DrawScope`.
I have tried to find them as children with no luck.